# Building OLTP DB from Datalake?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl, amazon-rds

I'm confused and having trouble finding examples and reference architecture where someone wants to extract data from an existing data lake (S3/Lakeformation in my case) and build a OLTP datastore that serves as an applications backend.  Everything I come across is an OLAP data warehousing pattern (i.e. ETL -> S3 -> Redshift -> BI Tools) where data is always coming IN to the datalake and warehouse rather than being pulled OUT.  I don't necessarily have a need for 'business analytics' but I do have a need for displaying graphs in web dashboards with large amounts of time series data points underneath for my websites users.

1. What if I want to automate pulling extracts of a large dataset in the datalake and build a relational database with some useful data extracts from the various datasets that need to be queried by the hand full instead of performing large analytical queries against a DW?
2. What if I just want an extract of say, stock prices over 10 years, and just get the list of unique ticker symbols for populating a drop down on a web app?  I don't want to query an OLAP data warehouse every time to get this, so I want to have my own OLTP store for more performant queries on smaller datasets that will have much higher TPS?
3. What if I want to build dashboards for my web app's customers that display graphs of large amounts of time series data currently sitting in the datalake/warehouse.  Does my web app connect directly to the DW to display this data?  Or do I pull that data out of the datalake or warehouse and into my application DB on some schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My views on your 3 questions:

1. Why not just use the same ETL solution that is being used to load the datalake?
2. Presumably your DW has a Ticker dimension that has unique records for each Ticker symbol? What's the issue with querying this as it would be very fast to get the unique Ticker symbols from it?
3. It depends entirely on your environment/infrastructure and what you are doing with the data - so there is no generic answer anyone could provide you with. If your webapp is showing aggregations of a large volume of data then your DW is probably better at doing those aggregations and passing the aggregated data to your webapp; if the webapp is showing unaggregated data (and only a small subset of what is held in your DW, such as just the last week's data) then loading it into your application DB might make more sense

The pros/cons of any solution would also be heavily influenced by your infrastructure e.g. what's the network performance like between your DW and application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  
2. My issue with querying the DW for unique tickers is that it's just a handfull of data thats going to be queried quite often, which from my understanding is more of an OLTP use case that redshift isn't necessarily optimized for at scale.

Comment: Sorry, re-read your use case for no. 2 and agree that you wouldn't want to read the OLAP every time for this. Reference data for an app needs to be held within/close to the app - so I'd extract it from the OLAP and load it into the app DB